# date is implicitly converting to integer

Tags: postgresql, date, time, plpgsql

I am learning PL/pgSQL. I want to print the next 15 day's dates in one column.
So I created the following function:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION p15d() 
  RETURNS table(date_ date ) AS $$ 
  declare 
  i date := current_date; 
  ii date := current_date + integer '15'; 
 BEGIN 
  loop 
      return query execute'select ' || (i + interval '1 day')::date; 
      i = i + 1; 
      exit when i = ii; 
  end loop; 
 END; 
 $$ 
 LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But when I run this function I get this error:

```
ERROR:  structure of query does not match function result type
DETAIL:  Returned type integer does not match expected type date in column 1.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function p15d() line 8 at RETURN QUERY
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't require  dynamic SQL for adding an interval to an expression .

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION p15d() 
  RETURNS table(date_ date ) AS $$ 
  declare 
  i date := current_date; 
  ii date := current_date + integer '15'; 
 BEGIN 
  loop 
      return query  select ( i + interval '1 day' )::date; 
      i = i + 1; 
      exit when i = ii; 
  end loop; 
 END; 
 $$ 
 LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But, there is no need for such a function, Postgres already has `generate_series` function which gives what you want.

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION p15d() 
  RETURNS table(date_ date ) AS 
 $$ 
   select generate_series(current_date+1,current_date + 15,interval '1 day' )::date; 
 $$ 
 LANGUAGE SQL;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=3a86784339675aa348d7adeb4c049b12)

Answer (score 1):

The cause for your error message is that the query you execute is (today):

```
select 2019-03-02
```

Now 2019 minus 3 minus 2 is 2014, which is an integer.